# How to implement string[] into string[] in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, winforms, streamreader

I want to implement '`string[] loadedText`' into '`string[] dataList`', but I keep getting an error saying "`Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'`".

```
string[] dataList = new string[1800];
StreamReader loadNewData = new StreamReader("podaciB.txt");
int i = 0;
while (i < 1800)
{
    string[] loadedData = loadNewData.ReadLine().Split(';');
    dataList[i] = loadedData;
    i++;
}
```

I need the '`dataList`' array that will contain 1800 'loadedData' arrays which contain 4 strings in them.

Comment: your `loadedData` is an array of string and `dataList` as well. But when you access `dataList[i]` you are in a string right now and compiler waiting a string to assign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need an *array of array of strings*, something like `string[][]`.

You can do it like this:

```
string[][] dataList = new string[1800][];
StreamReader loadNewData = new StreamReader("podaciB.txt");
int i = 0;
while (i < 1800)
{
    string[] loadedData = loadNewData.ReadLine().Split(';');
    dataList[i] = loadedData;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`loadNewData.ReadLine().Split(';');` returns array of string and you are storing array of strings into `dataList[i]` i.e. string element of string array. This is the reason behind error which you mentioned in your question

If you want to store `loadNewData.ReadLine().Split(';');`  into an array then I would suggest you to use nested list `List<List<string>>`

Something like,

```
List<List<string>> dataList = List<List<string>>();
StreamReader loadNewData = new StreamReader("podaciB.txt");
int i = 0;
while (i < 1800)
{
    var innerList = loadNewData.ReadLine().Split(';').ToList();
    dataList.Add(innerList);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays):

```
string[][] dataList = new string[1800][];
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are splitting `loadedNewData`, you receive `string[]` already, because `Split()` function returns `string[]`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer